# Как разбить строку на массив слов и запушить в массив первый символ каждого слова?

Tags: javascript

`var letters = [];
var row = 'Some Text Here';`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var letters = [];
var row = 'Some Text Here';

const b = row.split` `; // Разбиваем по пробелу
b.forEach((el,i) => letters.push(el[0])); // И пушим первый элемент в массив letters 
console.log(letters);
```

Comment: `row.split().forEach(el => letters.push(el[0]));` Более короткий вариант :)

Comment: Вы лучше объясните, как работает **row.split` `**?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko точно также как и `row.split(" ")`Еще вопросы?

Comment: Да это я понимаю, но КАК оно работает и почему?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я же написал точно также как и обычный `split` такое редко кто пишет не пугайтесь можно абсолютно все  скобки в методах  заменить на такие обратные кавычки и это все будет валидно.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов, как Вы к этому пришли?)

Comment: @Дмытрык может быть, вы объясните, как оно работает?)

Comment: @Дмытрык Дело было давно хотел написать свой палиндром ) который отличается от прочих.В результате выяснил вот это. )

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, если Вы на счет вызова через обратные кавычки? Я не в курсе.

Comment: @Дмытрык именно про вызов метода без скобок.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если вы хотите получить какую нибудь ссылку (документацию) про вызов метода через backslash такого нету пока что.Абсолютно НЕ ГДЕ.Ну или можете поискать если найдете скиньте мне ссылку  :)

Comment: Вот что-то похожее https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Tagged_templates

Comment: Это я читал это не вызов метода через обратные кавычки.

Comment: Это и есть вызов функции myTag через обратные кавычки)

Comment: Не буду спорить )

Comment: Это есть на learn.javascript в статье про шаблоны строк, там был пример с локализацией https://learn.javascript.ru/es-string#funktsii-shablonizatsii

Answer (score 2):

С помощью map можно сделать ещё короче.
Map возвращает новый массив, нам больше не требуется создавать отдельную переменную с пустым массивом и постоянно вызывать push.

```js
var row = 'Some Text Here';

var b = row.split(' '); 
var letters = b.map((el,i) => el[0]);
console.log(letters);
```